# Exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find the EntityClass with id "xx"

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I know I'm doing something funky, and I have spent more than i care to admit debugging in the IDE, swapping annotations and reading other peoples questions & answers, but i'm truly failing.  So i'm willing to take the wrap from the replies at this stage.

Queue Entity:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity (name = "Queue")
@Table(name = "queues")
public class Queue implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuid", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "head", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private QueueItem head;

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tail", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private QueueItem tail;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "queue", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<QueueItem> queueItems = new ArrayList<>();

\\getters & setters
```

QueueItem Entity:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity (name = "QueueItem")
@Table(name = "queue_items")
public class QueueItem implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuid", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private UUID uuid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="queue_id", nullable=false)
    private Queue queue;  //queue and position are unique

    @Column(name = "position", nullable = false)
    private Integer position;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
    private User user;

    public QueueItem( Queue queue, Integer position, User user ) {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.position = position;
        this.user = user;
        this.uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

\\getters & setters
```

I also have a User Entity which is simple.

My RestController QueueController calls a QueueService.createQueue.

```
@Component
public class QueueService {

    @Autowired
    private QueueRepository queueRepository;
    @Autowired
    private QueueItemService queueItemService;

    public Queue createQueue(final String name) {
        Queue queueToSave = new Queue(name);
        QueueItem sentinelQueueItem = queueItemService.createSentinelItem( queueToSave );
        queueToSave.setHead( sentinelQueueItem );
        queueToSave.setTail( sentinelQueueItem ); // make this a builder
        queueToSave.addtoQueueItemsList(sentinelQueueItem );
        return queueRepository.save(queueToSave);
    }
}
```

which as you can see interacts with a QueueItemService.

```
@Component
public class QueueItemService {

    @Autowired
    private QueueItemRepository queueItemRepository;
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    public QueueItem createSentinelItem( Queue queue) {

        UUID sentinelQueueUuid = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(String.format( "sentinal_{}", queue.getName()).getBytes());
        User sentinelUser = userService.getSentinelUser();
        QueueItem sentinelQueueItem = new QueueItem(sentinelQueueUuid , queue, 1, sentinelUser);
        return queueItemRepository.save(sentinelQueueItem);
    }
}
```

We are failing when saving here: `queueRepository.save(queueToSave)` or earlier `queueItemRepository.save(sentinelQueueItem)` if i try and save it first.

with error:

```
Unable to find click.whosnext.restapiback.domains.QueueItem with id 86bfd489-7ce0-3137-b714-79bc59b7685c; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find click.whosnext.restapiback.domains.QueueItem with id 86bfd489-7ce0-3137-b714-79bc59b7685c"
```

I've debugged and I feel like I end up with the object i want in the shape it should be ready for the queueRepo.save.  But i'm missing something obvious clearly.

Comment: You could try to add @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) to your OneToOne relations. After all: I'm not sure your solution will work, since in the Queue.java you define a OneToOne relation, and in QueueItem.java you define a ManyToOne relation back. A solution for your problem could be that you define a new column in QueueItem.java like 'type' that could have the value of HEAD/TAIL/??. Then you can create a normal bi-directional OneToMany and ManyToOne relation between Queue.java and QueueItem.java.

Comment: Why have you commented the "queueItemRepository.save()" ? You are currently adding a transient QueueItem to the Queue children list, that will not work because that QueueItem is unknown from a DB point of view. You need to save first the children, and add the children to the list while being sure that the association between the two is set (queueItem.queue must references the parent too)

Comment: Ah I think you're right, i have a OneToOne on head and tail, but I initialised with the head and the tail as the senintel, thinking it would be easier to check head == tail over null.  This is probably whats causing it.  

And that commented out is my bad, I had a builder in there that i swapped out and this code is copied and pasted inbetween that stage. 

I'll remove my Queue create initing with a head and tail of the same QueueItem

Comment: So I don't know exactly which is the issue, but I have (had) some circular dependency where i couldn't save one without the other etc...  I removed all the restrictions on the entities and it all works but without the database owning the nullable or uniqueness.  I'll work on that next :)